# MySQL "old version syntax"

Tags: mysql, sqlite

im currently porting my SQLite database to MySQL, just made a script to change all INSERT's and more to MySQL but im sometimes getting an "old version syntax error":

```
INSERT INTO players(id, name) VALUES (21457, '/Gohst_Killer67\');
```

The Database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(40))
```

I have alot usernames saved, but those / or \ keeps raising those error messages. I hope theres a way to fix it without editing all names which contain / or .

Thanks

Comment: Probably \ is taken as an escape character and using \\ would fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql the way is-

```
Hitesh> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(40));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec)

Hitesh> INSERT INTO players(id, name) VALUES (21457, '/Gohst_Killer67\'');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
```

for special character you should use \ before it. like i have used `\'` in insert.

You can disable backslash escapes by setting  [NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-mode.html)   in the SQL mode:

```
SET @old_sql_mode=@@sql_mode;
SET @@sql_mode=CONCAT_WS(',', @@sql_mode, 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES');
Hitesh> INSERT INTO players(id, name) VALUES (21457,   "/Gohst_Killer67'");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
```

for insert  single quote you can put string in "" when insert or vice versa like i did. other wise you can use quote function [quote](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_quote)

Comment: Ye it seems like to work but there are alot of These in mY Database conversation.. Is there a way to fix them all without Editing each error manuall?

Comment: @Fragkiller you can disable sql mode in my post, it disable the escape sequence